# how do i stop a service started by a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that listens for an sms or call from a specific number. when it triggers it starts a location service which runs from that point on.

I need to be able to stop this service once it is no longer needed from my app.
My app does not need to be running for this broadcast receiver to trigger the service.

Any advice would be very much appreciated

Thank You

Comment: yes you can stop service on receiver

Comment: ok but it is an unknown on how long the receiver or should i say service will run for. that is why i need to know how to hook into the receiver at a later point and manually stop it

Comment: its depends on you when person out of their recognised location i.e take some km. So, check if person out that location with 5 km then stop update of location.

Comment: the location of the phone could change over a long period of time and/or distance. for example could move 100km over the space of an hour

Comment: So, something you decide the radius of that person.It could help you to remove service to out of radius

Comment: why dont u just add an if clause into ur receiver that searches the intent for an extra like `Intent.getBooleanExtra("varaible",false)` if this extra applies --> is true u stop it then u just add some way to fire this intent from ur activity